# Calculate Moving Average - MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I would like to calculate the moving average of 4 rows. I have searched online and tried different methods but I have not got the result. This is an example of my table

```
    Week    DATES       CURRYR            MOVINGAVG
       1    4/7/2017    351,929.76  
       2    4/14/2017   352,202.99  
       3    4/21/2017   483,987.60  
       4    4/28/2017   358,125.55  (AVG CURRYR 0F #1-#4)
       5    5/5/2017    335,180.47  (AVG CURRYR 0F #2-#5)
       6    5/12/2017   421,693.56  (AVG CURRYR 0F #3-#6)
       7    5/19/2017   394,410.34  (AVG CURRYR 0F #4-#7)
       8    5/26/2017   437,064.82  (AVG CURRYR 0F #5-#8)
       9    6/2/2017    536,921.87  (AVG CURRYR 0F #6-#9)
      10    6/9/2017    358,177.15  (AVG CURRYR 0F #7-#10)
      11    6/16/2017   418,651.36  (AVG CURRYR 0F #8-#11)
      12    6/23/2017   402,590.79  (AVG CURRYR 0F #9-#12)
      13    6/30/2017   407,775.24  (AVG CURRYR 0F #10-#13)
      14    7/7/2017    391,020.15  (AVG CURRYR 0F #11-#14)
```

And so no....

Is there a way I could execute this in MS ACCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asusme your real data have a few more things to join on in which case you'd need to bring them into the sub query. Also this only works because the `Weeks` are a complete list (i.e. you don't have week 15, week 16, week 18, week 20, that's going to mess it up and the logic would need to be changed).

```
SELECT o.Week
    ,o.DATES
    ,o.CURRYR
    ,(
        SELECT avg(CurrYR)
        FROM Table1 i
        WHERE i.week <= o.week
            AND i.week >= (o.week - 3)
        having count(*) >=4
        ) AS MovingAverage
FROM Table1 o
```

.

```
Week    DATES       CURRYR      MovingAverage
1       4/7/2017    351,929.76  
2       4/14/2017   352,202.99  
3       4/21/2017   483,987.60  
4       4/28/2017   358,125.55  386561.475
5       5/5/2017    335,180.47  382374.1525
6       5/12/2017   421,693.56  399746.795
7       5/19/2017   394,410.34  377352.48
8       5/26/2017   437,064.82  397087.2975
9       6/2/2017    536,921.87  447522.6475
10      6/9/2017    358,177.15  431643.545
11      6/16/2017   418,651.36  437703.8
12      6/23/2017   402,590.79  429085.2925
13      6/30/2017   407,775.24  396798.635
14      7/7/2017    391,020.15  405009.385
```

Comment: Thank you Brad. It works, but for some reason the query is changing the values in the CURRYR column and hence the movingaverage is different. Would you by any chance know why would that be?

Comment: @Reems This query is averaging the `CURYR` column. It sounds like in your real data you're trying to average another column which wasn't in your question. Change `CURYR` in the subquery to whatever that column is.

Comment: I have the exact same columns, however these columns were taken from another query. Sorry if i am not explaining it properly

Comment: @Reems I'm not sure how the values in `CURRYR` could be changed. In the sql above they're just passed through directly from the table/your underlying query.  Can you start working backwards? remove the moving average part. Still the same result? If what I have as `Table1` is actually another query start breaking that apart.

Comment: If i remove the moving average part the values in CURRYR goes back to actual values. I am stumped as to why the values would be changing in that column.

Comment: Did you figure out what was happening?

Comment: i couldn't figure out, but i worked around, I save Week, DATES and CURRYR to a table and then did the query to calculate the moving average. now it works well... Thanks for helping me out, the query works well.